# "bwrap" is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a class extending the old Ext.Panel class. I'm now trying to migrate my application with help of the migration guide provided by sencha. I'm using a modification of the ext3 "Portal"-Example.

When trying to load my application i get some "deprecated" and "breaking" errors with a good explaination. But there is one error, i can't fix. It says "portal.bwrap is undefined" as mentioned above, "portal" is a subclass of Ext.Panel. In ext3 there was a property "bwrap" in the new ext there is not. And it is not documented neither in the compatibility layer nor in the migration guide how to fix this in ext4.

Here are the two places where bwrap is used:

```
 constructor : function(portal, cfg){
    this.portal = portal;
    Ext.dd.ScrollManager.register(portal.body);
    Ext.ux.Portal.DropZone.superclass.constructor.call(this, portal.bwrap.dom, cfg);
    portal.body.ddScrollConfig = this.ddScrollConfig;
},

[...]

getGrid : function(){
    var box = this.portal.bwrap.getBox();
    box.columnX = [];
    this.portal.items.each(function(c){
         box.columnX.push({x: c.el.getX(), w: c.el.getWidth()});
    });
    return box;
},
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bwrap was a div that wrapped that panel body. It no longer exists. Without seeing the code I can't say what you should do, but chances are you should either refer to the main panel element or the body itself.

FYI the portal example is already ported to 4.

Comment: Thank you so far! I added the code of the two occurances. I noticed, that the example has been ported to ext4. But we did a lot of modification to the classes. And in the ext4 example there is only a "classes.js" file with all the interesting classes in one line with unusable variable names. So i can't use that to port the changes.

Comment: The only chance i had unfortunately was to reimplement everything based on the ext4 portal demo. So thanks for the answer.